# Why submit input style does not apply on Chrome neither on Safari (Mac), but only if I apply a background-color?

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome, safari

I have a simple Web page in which the CSS style rules do not apply on
the button of the form, if I am on Chrome or Safari (Mac OS X, Yosemite).
It does apply on Firefox. And it does apply on Chrome and Safari if I
use a background-color property.

Look at the following example. The `save` button does not have `Roboto Mono` font, as it should be. This problem occurs only if you open the
page on Chrome or Safari. It works perfect on Firefox.

On top of that, if I apply a style like `background-color` on the button, then the font `Roboto Mono`, suddenly, works as expected and it is applied on the button too.

Here is the code that I have used.

http://jsbin.com/foqiso/edit?html,css,output

Any clue why the button does not take the font specified, but only if

- I am on Firefox OR
- I am on Chrome or Safari and I apply a background-color

?

**Update:** There is also another workaround. Instead of using `<input type="submit" value="Save">`, if I use `<button type=submit>Save</button>`, then `button` is styled with the font I am expecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its your webkit styling. Add this:

```
input[type=submit]{
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}
```

This is Webkit only

Cheers

Comment: Ooooh. That's a very good hint that you gave me. But I believe that the correction should be `-webkit-appearance: button` instead. Do you agree? This does not throw away all the styling but applies the font style as expected and I can now see the "Roboto Mono" applied to the button. If you are ok with that, please, edit your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: YEs that should be great too for the `button`(`none` was for basic and button is more for modern browsers that will take it rather than older browsers] but good call too  :)